# Vagrant synced_folder fmode vs file_mode

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, hyper-v

Using Vagrant one has to use configs like these for usage with Hyper-V vs Virtualbox:

**(Virtualbox)**

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www/btoc/", mount_options: ["fmode=666", "dmode=777"]
```

**(Hyper-V)**

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www/btoc/", mount_options: ["file_mode=0777", "dir_mode=0777"]
```

**The only difference is fmode/dmode vs file_mode/dir_mode.**
But this leads to not being startable on respectively the other one.
Vagrant up dies with cryptic messages / problems when trying it.

Is there a workaround for this?
Why was this decision made?
Is it simply a bad decision or am I missing something obvious?

Using Vagrant 2.2.3 on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you have different settings per provider, you can override the setting in a provider specific section:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "xxxx"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb, override|
    override.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www/btoc/", mount_options: ["fmode=666", "dmode=777"]
  end

  config.vm.provider "hyperv" do |h, override|
    override.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www/btoc/", mount_options: ["file_mode=666", "dir_mode=777"]
  end

end
```

Comment: Awesome!
This solves my initial pain - Thank you!
Though the decision to name a switch differently on different plattforms for a cross-plattform software seems still questionable at least?

Comment: it could be but since vagrant relies on those provider and the behavior from the provider is different, vagrant needs some support from the vagrantfile to know how to make it work for your use case with all different platform